# How to properly use tf.scatter_update for N-Dimensional Updating?

Tags: python, tensorflow, bitmask

I've been trying to make an N-Dimensional update using `tf.scatter_update` (after `tf.scatter_nd` was failing due to shape mismatch). In general, these will be used to create masks for filtering slices of an incoming tensor.

Presumption is that input Tensor A is of shape (batch, i, j, k(depth)).
I am only interested in modifying **i,j** values for **all k**, and for **all b**.

MWE:

```
import tensorflow as tf

b, i, j, k = 64, 128, 128, 256
A = tf.random_uniform(shape=(64, 128, 128, 256), dtype='int32', seed=1234) # Batch, i, j, k

mask = tf.ones(shape=(b,i,j,k), dtype='int32')

# Placeholder for more complicated index Tensor. GPU Ignores OOB indices.
indices = tf.random_uniform(shape=(b, 25, k, 2), dtype='int32', seed=4321) # Index number, k, i-j coord.

updates = tf.random_uniform(shape=(i, j, k), dtype='int32', seed=1111)
scatter = tf.scatter_update(mask, indices, updates)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(scatter)
```

Resulting in:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read'

I have tried this via Python Script, Python Notebook, and with/without Eager Execution. No luck.

Input absolutely must be a tensor, as the idea is to sparsely update this tensor midway through a series of operations.

Is there something fundamental I'm missing regarding `tf.scatter_update`? Would `tf.scatter_nd` be more suited? If so, what are the differences, specifically with indices for the updates.

When referencing [tf.scatter_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) documentation, the examples are basic and utilise constants; I'm having difficulty applying this to a more realistic situation and problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow's documentation makes use of all the *scatter* operations (such as scatter_nd_add, etc) by inputing the *ref* arguments as a **tf.Variable**:

> ref: A mutable Tensor. Must be one of the following types: blablabla. A mutable Tensor. **Should be from a Variable node**.

I had the same issue and it works fine when used on a tf variable for *ref*. All the other arguments can remain whatever they are I guess, but I did not investigate thoroughly.

Comment: I thought this to be the case. Maybe it's a symptom of trying to develop in an isolated environment, as I'm mocking the input tensor, rather than grabbing it from somewhere in the network.